# Get the band at which the packets are being sent

Tags: android, tcp

I'm making an android application where I'm intercepting the TCP packets sent from the phone/to the phone (UL/DL). I'm getting the information like length of the packets, port etc but I can't find a way to get the band at which the packets are being sent. 
Any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: Count the bytes in a specified time range like 10 sec. then compute the bandwidth.

Comment: I'm not looking at calculating the throughput or speed. I want the bandwidth like x MHz.  Also I would want the original value, not the calculated one. Any clue on that?

Comment: Mhz has nothing to do with bandwidth. That can defin a band;) You cannot get the bandwidth a provider gives you. There is no parameter or server you can ask. You have to compute and make a guess. You can make the guess better when you have meta data like provider name and products etc.